# Showing a Container Item in a Repeater only if it exists (is not Null) in the Database

Tags: vb.net, repeater, visibility

Currently, the following code shows a blank line if Address2 (which comes from the database) is Null. How can I condition on the value of <%#Container.DataItem("Address2")%> so I can get rid of the blank line if Address2 does not exist (or is Null) in the database? If code in the code-behind is needed, please provide in VB.

```
<asp:repeater id="rptLabels" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <span style="text-align:left;">         
                 <%#Container.DataItem("Address")%><br />             
                 <%#Container.DataItem("Address2")%><br />
             </span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing more in the code behind where I am more comfortable than the aspx page to resolve this issue.